How to get historical index stock composition of Nifty 50, Nifty Next 50 and other indexes over the years?
I need to fetch the constituent stocks of Nifty 50 over the years, say starting from 2015. If I am not wrong the index weightage is reviewed and updated every 6 months. I need to know—starting 2015—what were the constituents of index and how it changed (new entrants and exits) during each review.
I posed this question to Microsoft Co-pilot but it spit out links like below

https://www.nseindia.com/reports-indices-historical-index-data
https://www.niftyindices.com/reports/historical-data
https://www.wsj.com/market-data/quotes/index/IN/NIFTY50/historical-prices
https://in.investing.com/indices/s-p-cnx-nifty-historical-data

But these only provide historical index value and not the constituents.
How to get historical index stock composition of Nifty 50, Nifty Next 50 and other indexes over the years?

Hidden in the other links, Co-Pilot apparently already gave you the correct link:
https://www.niftyindices.com/reports/historical-data
Here, on top, pick "Archives of Daily/Monthly Reports".
In the next selection box, pick "Market Capitalisation, Weightage, Beta for NIFTY 50 & NIFTY Next 50" and a month to get some detailed data for those two indexes (as csv).
Or pick "Indices - Market Capitalisation & Weightage" and a month to get the constituents and weightages for the two and some more indexes (as pdf).
Looks as if you need to do some clicking to get all data you want (there is data for every month), and someone somewhere might have already done this and might provide a simpler download option, but this seems to be the most official source for your data.
